# A weird execute result of express middleware

Tags: node.js, express

My code:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set('port',3332);

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    res.send('OK');
    next();
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log('middleware 1');
    next();
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log('middleware 2');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.set('port'),function(){
    console.log('nodejs start listen 3332 port!');
});
```

nodejs server output:
nodejs start listen 3332 port!

middleware 1

middleware 2

middleware 1

middleware 2

Why each middleware is fired 2 times, can anybody help me to explain it. I know if remove `next()` in `app.get()`, it will be fired 1 time. Is the chain of middleware a circle chain？ Thank you.

Modify the code,add `next()` in last `app.use()`. There is another question:

```
var http = require("http");

var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set('port',3332);

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    res.send('OK');
    next();
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log('middleware 1');
    next();
});

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log('middleware 2');
    next(); // new add
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.set('port'),function(){
    console.log('nodejs start listen 3332 port!');
});
```

Middelware registed by `app.use()` is called when I access the url first time. But seconde time, third time access the url both in browser and cmd command line,it will not be called.
Why that?

Comment: I think, it is because you are using  next() function in app.get and app.use, where app.use is always call when you are try to call app.get

Comment: I have tested if I remove next() in app.get(), then it would not call callback function which is registed in app.use(). Do you test that?

Comment: I am not using next() in get(). We are using return in get().

Answer (score 3):

This is `favicon.ico` request. Browser tries to load favicon each time you request website index page. Output url to see it in console. Use curl/wget to run requests.

Comment: I have updated my node to newest version, it is ok when using curl to call url. Thank you. And I have also a question if I add next() in last app.use() in my code, and then app.use middleware is only called when use curl to access the url  first time. But seconde time, third time ... middleware registed by app.use is not called. why that?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you actually means. So it's hard to say without watching the code.

Comment: You can run my last block code. At my pc,after loading the code, then access the url: localhost:3332, at server side ,it will output 2 lines log. But when refresh the web page again, it does not output any logs. I think it should output the same 2 lines log, but it not.

Comment: I run this code and made request three times. I get output for each request. https://asciinema.org/a/3l0wo0oztpytfchh8p4kv5296

Comment: If the problem is currently not solved publish it as a new question. It will bring more people to see it and help you. And mark my reply as an answer, please.

Comment: I update my nodejs, It's ok when using browser. So I think the problem is not related to favicon.ico request . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I update my nodejs, It's ok when using browser. So I think the problem is related to low version nodejs . Thank you everyone.